# Android keyboard closes and opens when I tap on any word while typing

Tags: java, android, keyboard

I am facing a weird issue in my native android app where the android keyboard closes and reopens when I tap between words in a sentence. I have tried using   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" and without it as well.

This is the 8 seconds video link showing the behaviour
[Video Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18agntb-lIEVQkwYTaA5jO1VQ65nv4kEA/view?usp=sharing)
I am expecting that the keyboard does not close and open causing the screen flicker

Comment: From having written keyboards-  that's generally seen when something restarts the input connection.  If you're using a basic EditText, I'd check for any code that may be requesting focus or removing focus in your code.  If you're using something else, it may be a break in that UI element.